# (React-Native) undefined is not a constructor evaluating 'new FormData()'

Tags: javascript, react-native

for the past 2 days I struggled with this problem and can't figure it out.
I don't understand this error. this is my code:

```
try{
var formData = new FormData();
} catch (error) {
console.error('FormData ERROR', error);
}
```

and this is the error:

> 017-06-21 13:49:02.761 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript]
>   'FormData ERROR', { [TypeError: undefined is not a constructor
>   (evaluating 'new FormData()')] line: 98419, column: 36, sourceURL:
>   'http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false'
>   }

Do i have to add support for FormData in ReactNative 0.45.0?
please help

Comment: FormData is undefined, can you make sure that the object exists in your code?

Comment: @D-reaper how do i do that? FormData i think is included in react-native / libraries / network

Comment: console.log(FormData). If it is undefined, then you just have to make sure that you include it in your code.

Comment: after console.log(FormData) i get undefined. i tried import { FormData } from 'react-native'; but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

First of all, I found something (*don't know from where i had these "tips"*) in my index.ios.js and removed them

```
// const _XHR = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?  
//     GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :           
//     GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest                     

// XMLHttpRequest = _XHR;

// // FormData = global.originalFormData;
```

Then I found out that my debugger (Chrome or RNDebugger) messed with my network requests and that was bad for multipart image object. (*strange?!*)

finally i got it working with this code:

```
var fdObject = new FormData();
fdObject.append('avatar', {uri: PicturePath, name: 'avatar.jpg', type: 'image/jpg'});
options.method = POST;
options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
options.body = fdObject;
fetch("http://api.com/post-my-image", options);
```

Answer (score 5):

I got into this problem as well and that's because I have imported them on top.
If you have done like what I did:

```
import { FormData } from 'react';
```

or

```
import { FormData } from 'react-native';
```

Just remove "FormData" from your imports and it will work like magic. FormData doesn't have to be imported for it to be working.

Comment: @Cristi Milea check out my answer if you haven't got the issue resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. FormData doesn't have to be imported.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you are FormData is undefined. Since it is not part of react native, you probably have to download it from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).

```
npm install --save form-data
```

Then import it at the top of your file

```
import FormData from 'form-data';
```

Comment: i tried with this library and couldn't make it work on react-native

Comment: and also found out that FormData comes with RN https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/FormData.js

Answer (score 1):

if

```
import { FormData } from 'react-native';
```

didn't help then you can try to import directly:

```
import FormData from 'react-native/Libraries/Network/FormData';
```